# Laravel 5.2 Storage::makeDirectory($dir) is not creating directory

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, permissions, laravel-5

I am getting confused with this logic. I am using Laravel 5.2 Storage::makeDirectory to create two paths, first (*video/*) is created correctly and the other (*thumbnails/*) don't.

```
$user = 1;

if(!File::exists(public_path() . "/video/$user"))
{
    Storage::makeDirectory(public_path() . "/video/$user", 0777);
}

$file = rand(1111111111111, 9999999999999);
$imgpath = public_path() . "/thumbnails/$file";

if(!File::exists($imgpath))
{
    Storage::makeDirectory($imgpath, 0777);
}
```

Here is the permission configuration:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 28 19:33 thumbnails/
drwxrwxrwx 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 29 15:21 video/
```

I also could create a directory from cli with the given string from **$imgpath**:

```
mkdir /home/ubuntu/workspace/site/public/thumbnails/6300643852187
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm... i don't see any errors at now, can you just try to do `mkdir($imgpath, 0777, false);` without any conditions?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide `$imgpath` listing, please? (i know this is different each time, but anyway i need to see it)

Comment: it does not contain anything, since the paths aren't being created because of... Idk... That is my question indeed. Why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I figured out what was going on.

`File::exists(public_path() . "/video/$user")` is looking for this:

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/site/public/video/*N*

And `Storage::makeDirectory(public_path() . "/video/$user")` is creating a directory in:

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/site/storage/app/public/video/*N*

So I can go to **site/config/filesystems.php** and change the routes for *app* and *app/public* ; you can check them by using the helper `storage_path('app')`. 
But, instead, I decided to save the videos in the ***storage/app/public/video*** and ***storage/app/public/thumbnails***, and I am getting some package's error.

But, both paths are writable and should be working by now.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel 5.2

```
if(!Storage::disk('public')->has('image/path/directory/')){
    Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('image/path/directory/');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to force it to do it like this

```
$dr = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$is_dir = File::makeDirectory($dr.'/uploads/images/'.$user.'/thumbs/', 0755, true, true);
```

**0755 is folder permissions**

**1st true  is recursive creation of folders**

**2nd true is to force it to do it**